# Need hierarichal data from 3 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following tables:

**UserMaster**:

`UserId Int, UserName Varchar(200),AddedBy Int`

```
UserId     EmpName           AddedBy
1          admin             0
2          SubAdmin1         1
3          SubAdmin2         1    
4          Vikas             2      
5          Mohit             4
6          Atul              5 
7          Vishal            6
8          Mani              3
9          Sunny             8
```

**SalesMaster**:

`SalesId Int, UserId Int (FK_UserMaster_UserId) , Price Int`

```
SalesId  UserId  Price

1        1       100         
2        2       200      
3        3       300      
4        4       500     
5        5       100
6        6       200
7        7       111
8        8       222
9        9       333
```

Case 1: Now I want the price total of all the users who are under the one particular user and its own price also.
Means If i consider UserId=1 , Then the price will be calculated for all users where Column value in AddedBy=1 
and their lower level employees.
Means the total Price of users will be calulated for the users having UserId are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Case 2: Similarly, If i want to calculate the total price under UserId=3(SubAdmin2) then the total price from the salesMaster will be calculated for the Users having UserId are: 3,8,9

The Result of first Case should be:

```
UserId     Price
1          2066
```

The Result of Second Case should be:

```
UserId     Price
3          300+222+333
```

Please Help

Thanks & Regards
Nitin

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select @UserId as UserId
    union all
    select um.UserId
    from UserMaster as um
        inner join cte as c on c.UserId = um.AddedBy
)
select sum(s.Price)
from cte as c
    inner join SalesMaster as s on s.UserId = c.UserId
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e5f8/2)</kbd>**